# Android Virtual Device (AVD) for Google+ development on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

One of the requirements of Google+ platform for Android on the [developers.Google.com](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) site is that you must have

> A physical device to use for developing and testing because Google Play services can only be installed on an emulator with an AVD that runs Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

Since i do not have a Android powered device, what emulator if any can i use in place of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to say, if you wnat to test GooglePlay service on an AVD, you should create a AVD with a minimum API level 17 (4.2.2)

API level is an option you must configure when you create a new AVD.

Comment: What a relief.Thanks mate.